# Cannot deploy django project with postgres database in azure

Tags: django, postgresql, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I know it may be a novice problem but I got stuck here for quite some time.

In my azure account I wanted to deploy my django-postgresql project in a subdomain. so I did the following steps,

- Created a python webapp with linux resource
- Created a postgresql server (single server) with the same resource
- Setup CI/CD in **Development center**
- Also set the production.py file in my project and set those variable values in the **Configuration** of my App service.
- I successfully created my database in postgresql using azure CLI (This is the only step I use CLI in this process)
- Then I opened my SSH session and activated antenv. After that I ran the **python manage.py migrate** command and got the following error....

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

FYI, I am not using docker and azure CLI for creating webapp. I only used azure CLI to create the database.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, John. Would you mind accept my answer for others to refer if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message, your app service could not connect to server, here are something you need to check:

1. Check if you already set all of the required app settings like mine:
   [image]
2. Check if you enable the `Allow access to Azure Service` in Azure Database for PostgreSQL server's Firewall rules:
   [image]

If you are new to this, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fpostgresql%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json&tabs=bash%2Cclone#1-set-up-your-initial-environment) first.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the settings files for multiple deployments. Most probably one of your deployment settings uses local postgresql another one uses azure postgresql. Then because of wrong import or another reason, azure webapp uses host of local deployment (which is localhost if not provided).